# Possible to change a datasource property in Power App dynamically?

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to work through a proof of concept app that needs to talk to a 3rd party API.  The initial step is to get a token from the 3rd party, which I've done by creating a custom connection which uses no security.  Once I get the token, I need to make additional queries to this 3rd party API, each of which will require the token being passed.  So, I've created a second custom connector which uses API KEY for security.  When I manually create a new connection for this 2nd custom connector, I'm prompted for the token and everything runs as expected. So I've now added both custom connectors to my canvas Power App, get the token I need from first custom connector in the app's OnStart event.  I'd now like to try to change the connector properties for the second custom connector to use the dynamically generated token.

Is this possible?  If not, is there another approach I should be pursuing?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is possible via [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/policy-templates).  Haven't gotten it working yet, but hopefully soon...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).